# How can I get the Edith Downes stranger mission?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

I remember seeing a stranger mission from Edith Downes in Annesburg some time ago, but now it's gone. Does anyone know how I can get it again?

I'm currently at Chapter 6.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this website](https://gamewith.net/red-dead-redemption2/article/show/1252)

> Stranger Missions are side quests that can be found across the Wild
>   West [and] be given by strangers at specific locations. **The Strangers may**
>   **only appear during specific time of the day**.

The chapter you're in shouldn't matter since

> unlike narrative missions, Stranger's tasks can be started and
>   finished at any time.

[The website that quote is from](http://reddead.wikia.com/wiki/Strangers) also lists the different Stranger Missions, but I was unable to find the one that Edith Downes should trigger. Cross-referencing with her missions as listed [here](http://reddead.wikia.com/wiki/Edith_Downes), she doesn't seem to be involved in any. Are you maybe confused with *[Do Not Seek Absolution I](http://reddead.wikia.com/wiki/Do_Not_Seek_Absolution_I)*?

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure Do Not Seek Absolution is the mission. Though the wiki lists that mission as a main mission, it's shown as a stranger mission in rdr2. Perhaps there was a time limit? I'm pretty confused here.

Comment: Then has [your reputation](https://guides.gamepressure.com/red-dead-redemption-2/guide.asp?ID=47336) maybe changed since the first time you saw the mission showing up?

Comment: Before I saw the mission I had maximum high honor and still have

Comment: I'd seen the ED, and a couple of other side mission markers come and go a number of times before I visited And triggered them.  It did seem to be a time of day thing.